# How to share selected text from iphone book app on Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, sdk, share

I have iphone book app like all other text when tap and hold a specific words you will see a (copy,define) menu, I want to add another item which is (share) when the user tap it the sharing action sheet will pop up and the user can share that particular words on (Facebook , Twitter , mail or text).
Please help me with details, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can post the selected text to user's Facebook or Twitter or can create mail with selected text as body of that email.

Comment: Ad-J can you please give me a sample code? Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of tutorial available for Facebook and twitter integration. You can even use iDev's answer and replace intialText in twitter and description in facebook part with your selected text.

Answer (score 1):

social framework:

[share Fb or Twitter](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/)

```
- (IBAction)socialSheet:(id)sender {



       // create Facebook controller
        SLComposeViewController *socialController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        // add initial text
        [socialController setInitialText:@"Hello Facebook!"];

        // add an image for you optional 
        [socialController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.jpg"]];

        // add a URL for you optional 
        [socialController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wpguru.co.uk"]];

        // present controller
        [self presentViewController:socialController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Facebook Api

```
  -(void) postWithText: (NSString*) message_text
               ImageName: (NSString*) image_name
                     URL: (NSString*) url
                 Caption: (NSString*) caption
                    Name: (NSString*) name
          andDescription: (NSString*) description
    {

        NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       url, @"link",
                                       name, @"name",
                                       caption, @"caption",
                                       description, @"description",
                                       message, @"message_name",
                                       UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed: image_name]), @"picture",
                                       nil];

        if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound)
        {
            // No permissions found in session, ask for it
            [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                                  defaultAudience: FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
            {
                 if (!error)
                 {
                     // If permissions granted and not already posting then publish the story
                     if (!m_postingInProgress)
                     {
                         [self postToWall: params];
                     }
                 }
             }];
        }
        else
        {
            // If permissions present and not already posting then publish the story
            if (!m_postingInProgress)
            {
                [self postToWall: params];
            }
        }
    }

    -(void) postToWall: (NSMutableDictionary*) params
    {
        m_postingInProgress = YES; //for not allowing multiple hits

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 //showing an alert for failure
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"Post Failed"
                                           message:error.localizedDescription
                                           delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
             m_postingInProgress = NO;
         }];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I share a selected words using your code. I think I need to replace "Hello Facebook" with something but I don't know what it is, can you please help me?

Comment: @4slices you want to share the words using social framework else api

Comment: Yes I want to select particular phrase and share it.

Comment: check my answer and the link. image and url for optional to u. if won't ignore that